# Best and safest SEO way to hide h1 tags

Tags: html, css, seo

I want to use images that I created in PS for page titles. Because they will be images they will not be picked up by Google, etc. What is the best practice for hiding the `<h1>`? I was planning on setting the `<h1>` visibility to hidden. Is this ok to do?

**update**

I want to hide `<h1>` tag behind header image. I read how to do it if I just link an image (fine). My header is a little different. I have a background image taking up the whole header div. On top of that I have a flash file playing (mostly transparent) with some star burst effects. I want this to be SEO friendly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use it like this

```
<h1>
  <a href="http://website.com">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="My Website" />
  </a>
</h1>
```

Check this link from a Google Webmaster: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBLvn_WkDJ4

Comment: What if I want to use a background image?

Comment: "What if I want to use a background image?" Then you may as well include text in the H1 and use a set height, width, and "overflow:none" to hide the text.

Comment: I want to include text in it. That's the whole purpose. All I want to do is replace text with a more attractive image where the font looks nicer and hide the underlying text without getting black balled by Google. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to hide an `<h1>` tag behind an entire page header then you're probably abusing the `<h1>` tag and what you're doing would be considered black hat SEO as that would almost certainly not be considered a page title or heading and would ultimately get you in trouble with the search engines.

The `<h1>` is essentially to be used for the page heading which is like the page's or document's title. The big image at the top of a page really doesn't serve that purpose especially if it's the same from page-to-page.n If that is the case here then you definitely shouldn't be doing this. Also, if you need to hide something for the search engines' sake that usually is a good sign you probably shouldn't be doing something. There are exceptions but they are few and far between.

Comment: So is this valid and a good option for SEO? <h1>
            <img src="image.png" width="240" height="23" alt="My image text" />
   </h1>